# How to allow multiple instances of smooth touch scrolling to occur simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, scroll

I'm implementing a scrollable time selector into my mobile web application. It all works as intended, except that **when I start scrolling one of the columns and then immediately start scrolling the other column, the initial column instantly stops scrolling.**

This can make it unclear to the user which value is actually selected.

[UI working as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQqTI.png)
[UI after starting new scroll before previous scroll has completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA0nE.png)

Each scrollable column is set up as follows:

```html
<div style="overflow: scroll; scroll-snap-align: y mandatory;">
    <p></p> <!-- Buffer -->
    <p></p> <!-- Buffer -->
    <p style="scroll-snap-align: center;">0h</p>
    <p style="scroll-snap-align: center;">1h</p>
    <p style="scroll-snap-align: center;">2h</p>
    <p style="scroll-snap-align: center;">3h</p>
    <p style="scroll-snap-align: center;">4h</p>
    ...
    <p></p> <!-- Buffer -->
    <p></p> <!-- Buffer -->
</div>
```

The `scroll-snap-align: y mandatory` and `scroll-snap-align: center` make the elements naturally rest vertically centered, however triggering a `touchstart` or `touchmove` event mid-scroll appears to bypass this rule.

**Ideally, I would want the scroll to continue in the initial column until it either:**

- completes scrolling organically, or
- is directly interrupted by a touch event **made on itself** (not just any touch event made on the window)

I have tried disabling the `touchstart` and `touchmove` event on all other elements while the time selector is active.

```js
element.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}, {passive: false});

element.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}, {passive: false});
```

This works (the scroll is no longer interrupted when I swipe the screen over the disabled elements) but I can't disable the `touchstart` or `touchmove` event on the second column, because that also disables the ability to scroll that column.

I have tried setting `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` on the event listeners, however these had no effect.

I have also tried adding the following properties to the column `<div>` element

```css
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

These also had no effect.